# Lost a keyboard shortcut in Textmate - how to get it back?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I lost the greatest keyboard shortcut for Textmate: Command+/ to toggle commenting a line of code. I thought maybe it was some Bundle I installed so I removed them all, even deleted the app and Application Support directory, but it still didn't come back on re-install.

Maybe some other app is sucking up the shortcut I don't know how I'd go about tracking it down. Anyone have any ideas how I can get this shortcut back? I'd just re-create it in Textmate (you can record a key combo for most stuff in a Bundle) but I can't find any grammar for commenting. Help!

Answer (score 1):

For future generations: I was filtering the list of available bundles and removed the "Source" bundle. This is the one that contains they keyboard shortcuts that apply to multiple bundles, like the one to toggle commenting a line. Once I put the bundle back into the list, everything worked!